Are there any Crew alternatives that specifically cater to industries like retail, hospitality, or healthcare?
With Crew being discontinued, many businesses are searching for alternatives that meet the specific needs of industries like retail, hospitality, and healthcare. Are there any platforms tailored to these sectors that offer similar features and functionalities?

Hi. Please state the functions required, as some of us may not be familiar with "Crew".
